# Checking box values and disable button and show error message in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make sure the value of a particular set of boxes should not exceed the value of other sets of boxes...

Set 1:  Consultation fee, Other fee (total_fee will show the sum of these)

Set 2: cash, gpay, upi, card, others (total fee paid will show the sum of these)

The above action working pretty well...

Now, I want to make sure set 2 of total value should not exceed set 1 of total value. if so, I need to disable `btn` and also need to show an error message as "Sum of Receiving Payment exceeds Total Fee, Please Check!"...

How to do that?!

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <style>
    .error-text {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: red;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
  </style>


  <!-- Total Receiving Fee Calculation from Cash, Gpay, UPI, Card, Others -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      const paid_cash = document.getElementById("paid_cash");
      const paid_gpay = document.getElementById("paid_gpay");
      const paid_upi = document.getElementById("paid_upi");
      const paid_card = document.getElementById("paid_card");
      const paid_others = document.getElementById("paid_others");


      const total_fee_paid = document.getElementById("total_fee_paid");

      document.getElementById("paid_cash").addEventListener("input", sum);
      document.getElementById("paid_gpay").addEventListener("input", sum);
      document.getElementById("paid_upi").addEventListener("input", sum);
      document.getElementById("paid_card").addEventListener("input", sum);
      document.getElementById("paid_others").addEventListener("input", sum);

      function sum() {
        total_fee_paid.value = Number(paid_cash.value) + Number(paid_gpay.value) + Number(paid_upi.value) + Number(paid_card.value) + Number(paid_others.value);
      }

    });
  </script>


  <!-- Total Fee Calculation from Consultation fee and Other fee-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      const fee1 = document.getElementById("visit_cons_fee");
      const fee2 = document.getElementById("visit_other_fee");
      const total_fee = document.getElementById("total_fee");

      document.getElementById("visit_cons_fee").addEventListener("input", sum);
      document.getElementById("visit_other_fee").addEventListener("input", sum);

      function sum() {
        total_fee.value = Number(fee1.value) + Number(fee2.value);
      }

    });
  </script>





  <script type="text/javascript">
    // access the button from the html
    const btn = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");

    // access input boxes total_fee, total_fee_paid
    const [visit_cons_fee, visit_other_fee, paid_cash, paid_gpay, paid_upi, paid_card, paid_others] = [
      document.getElementById("visit_cons_fee"),
      document.getElementById("visit_other_fee"),
      document.getElementById("paid_cash"),
      document.getElementById("paid_gpay"),
      document.getElementById("paid_upi"),
      document.getElementById("paid_card"),
      document.getElementById("paid_others")

    ];

    // a generic method to validate if prices indicate
    // that 'submit' button should be disabled
    // as well as render an error notification
    const validatePrices = () => {
      btn.disabled = (+visit_cons_fee.value + +visit_other_fee.value < +paid_cash.value + +paid_gpay.value + +paid_upi.value + +paid_card.value + +paid_others.value);
      document.getElementById("error").innerText = (+visit_cons_fee.value + +visit_other_fee.value < +paid_cash.value + +paid_gpay.value + +paid_upi.value + +paid_card.value + +paid_others.value ?
        'Sum of Receiving Payment exceeds Total Fee, Please Check!' :
        ''
      );
    };

    // add event-listener to each input to invoke the validate method
    [paid_cash, paid_gpay, paid_upi, paid_card, paid_others].forEach(
      box => {
        box.addEventListener('keyup', validatePrices)
      });
  </script>






</head>

<body>



  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xl-4">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Consulation Fees:</b><span class="text-danger">*</span></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="visit_cons_fee" name="visit_cons_fee" required min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Other Charges:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="visit_other_fee" name="visit_other_fee" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Total Fee:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_fee" name="total_fee" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Payment by Cash:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="paid_cash" id="paid_cash" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>GPay Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="paid_gpay" name="paid_gpay" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>UPI Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="paid_upi" name="paid_upi" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Card Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="paid_card" id="paid_card" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Other Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="paid_others" id="paid_others" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Total Paid Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_fee_paid" name="total_fee_paid" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xl-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <center>
          <div id="error" class='error-text'>Test</div>
        </center><br/><br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end ">Add Visit</button>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems good, but you call `getElementById` before DOM is ready, which means all elements are not available, and you try to call `addEventListener` to undefined elements.

To avoid that situation, you can add

```
$(document).ready(() => { //your logic })
```

*Side note that I also improved your logic in `validatePrices`.*

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <style>
    .error-text {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: red;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
  </style>


  <!-- Total Receiving Fee Calculation from Cash, Gpay, UPI, Card, Others -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      const paid_cash = document.getElementById("paid_cash");
      const paid_gpay = document.getElementById("paid_gpay");
      const paid_upi = document.getElementById("paid_upi");
      const paid_card = document.getElementById("paid_card");
      const paid_others = document.getElementById("paid_others");


      const total_fee_paid = document.getElementById("total_fee_paid");

      paid_cash.addEventListener("input", sum);
      paid_gpay.addEventListener("input", sum);
      paid_upi.addEventListener("input", sum);
      paid_card.addEventListener("input", sum);
      paid_others.addEventListener("input", sum);

      function sum() {
        total_fee_paid.value = Number(paid_cash.value) + Number(paid_gpay.value) + Number(paid_upi.value) + Number(paid_card.value) + Number(paid_others.value);
      }
    });
  </script>


  <!-- Total Fee Calculation from Consultation fee and Other fee-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      const fee1 = document.getElementById("visit_cons_fee");
      const fee2 = document.getElementById("visit_other_fee");
      const total_fee = document.getElementById("total_fee");

      fee1.addEventListener("input", sum);
      fee2.addEventListener("input", sum);

      function sum() {
        total_fee.value = Number(fee1.value) + Number(fee2.value);
      }
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(() => {
      // access the button from the html
      const btn = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");

      // access input boxes total_fee, total_fee_paid
      const [visit_cons_fee, visit_other_fee, paid_cash, paid_gpay, paid_upi, paid_card, paid_others] = [
        document.getElementById("visit_cons_fee"),
        document.getElementById("visit_other_fee"),
        document.getElementById("paid_cash"),
        document.getElementById("paid_gpay"),
        document.getElementById("paid_upi"),
        document.getElementById("paid_card"),
        document.getElementById("paid_others")
      ];
      
      const total_fee = document.getElementById("total_fee");
      const total_fee_paid = document.getElementById("total_fee_paid");

      // a generic method to validate if prices indicate
      // that 'submit' button should be disabled
      // as well as render an error notification
      const validatePrices = () => {
        const invalid = Number(total_fee.value) < Number(total_fee_paid.value);
        btn.disabled = invalid;
        document.getElementById("error").innerText = invalid ?
          'Sum of Receiving Payment exceeds Total Fee, Please Check!' :
          ''
      };

      // add event-listener to each input to invoke the validate method
      [visit_cons_fee, visit_other_fee, paid_cash, paid_gpay, paid_upi, paid_card, paid_others].forEach(
        (item) => {
          item.addEventListener('keyup', validatePrices)
        });

    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Consulation Fees:</b><span class="text-danger">*</span></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="visit_cons_fee" name="visit_cons_fee" required min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Other Charges:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="visit_other_fee" name="visit_other_fee" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Total Fee:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_fee" name="total_fee" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Payment by Cash:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="paid_cash" id="paid_cash" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>GPay Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="paid_gpay" name="paid_gpay" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>UPI Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="paid_upi" name="paid_upi" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Card Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="paid_card" id="paid_card" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Other Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" name="paid_others" id="paid_others" placeholder="0" min="0">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="gr"><b>Total Paid Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_fee_paid" name="total_fee_paid" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xl-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <center>
          <div id="error" class='error-text'>Test</div>
        </center><br /><br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end ">Add Visit</button>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it is worth it to note that moving the code from the head to the bottom of the body is also a best practice, as well as containing the script in a single script tag, with only ONE ready listener (whether it is document.ready or an anonymous function)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery specific approach, it is a rework, but only because you are already loading the library. The only slight modifications to HTML being adding a class for payment specific fields as well as fee specific fields. This is a little more concise and readable, but ultimately, it is just another approach.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <style>
    .error-text {
      font-size: 14px;
      color: red;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Consulation Fees:</b><span class="text-danger">*</span></label><input type="number"
            class="form-control field-consult-fee" id="visit_cons_fee" name="visit_cons_fee" required min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Other Charges:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control field-consult-fee"
            id="visit_other_fee" name="visit_other_fee" min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Total Fee:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_fee"
            name="total_fee" value="" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Payment by Cash:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control field-payment-type"
            name="paid_cash" id="paid_cash" placeholder="0" min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>GPay Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control field-payment-type"
            id="paid_gpay" name="paid_gpay" placeholder="0" min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>UPI Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control field-payment-type"
            id="paid_upi" name="paid_upi" placeholder="0" min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Card Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control field-payment-type"
            name="paid_card" id="paid_card" placeholder="0" min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Other Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control field-payment-type"
            name="paid_others" id="paid_others" placeholder="0" min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="gr"><b>Total Paid Payment:</b></label><input type="number" class="form-control"
            id="total_fee_paid" name="total_fee_paid" value="" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="form-group text-center mb-4">
          <div id="error" class='error-text'>Test</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
      <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end ">Add Visit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // store our payment fields in variables
      const $paid_cash = $("#paid_cash")
      const $paid_gpay = $("#paid_gpay")
      const $paid_upi = $("#paid_upi")
      const $paid_card = $("#paid_card")
      const $paid_others = $("#paid_others")

      // store our fee fields in variables
      const $fee1 = $("#visit_cons_fee")
      const $fee2 = $("#visit_other_fee")
      const $total_fee = $("#total_fee")

      // store our totals in variables
      const $total_fee_paid = $("#total_fee_paid")
      const $field_payment_type = $("input.field-payment-type")

      // function to sum our payment fields and display the total
      function sumPayments() {
        const payment_fields = [$paid_cash, $paid_gpay, $paid_upi, $paid_card, $paid_others]
        const total_fee_paid = payment_fields.reduce((a, b) => a + +b.val(), 0)
        $total_fee_paid.val(total_fee_paid)
        validate()
      }

      // function to sum our fee fields and display the total
      function sumFees() {
        const fee_fields = [$fee1, $fee2];
        const total_fee = fee_fields.reduce((a, b) => a + +b.val(), 0)
        $total_fee.val(total_fee)
        validate()
      }

      // function to validate our payment does not exceed our fee
      function validate() {
        const $btn_submit = $("#btnSubmit")
        const total_fee = +$total_fee.val()
        const total_fee_paid = +$total_fee_paid.val()
        let disabled = false
        let error = "&nbsp;"

        if (total_fee_paid > total_fee) {
          error = "Total paid amount cannot be greater than total fee"
          disabled = true
        }

        $("#error").html(error)
        $btn_submit.attr("disabled", disabled)
      }

      // add event listeners to our payment_type fields 
      $field_payment_type.on('input', sumPayments)
      $field_consult_fee.on('input', sumFees)
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```